# How do you convert Coredata to be compatible with Android OS?

Tags: android, ios, core-data

I have an iOS application about 80% done coded in Coredata and Parse, and I have come to the conclusion that the App will have a better chance on the Android platform, so I am looking to convert my current code over to the Android platform without starting from scratch.

Is there a way to automatically convert Coredata to work with Android? Or does the conversion have to be done manually? Also, what does this process entail and how long would it generally take?

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way to automatically convert Coredata to work with Android.  Android does not come with an Object-Relational Mapping tool out of the box like iOS does.  You have to either create your own SQLite database using a [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) or you can use an ORM library.  There are several to choose from:  [Cupboard](https://bitbucket.org/qbusict/cupboard), [Sugar ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/), and [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml) are a few examples.

Answer (score 0):

As @James McCracken said there's no easy way to port your coredata work to android.
However there's [realm](http://realm.io/) which works as a replacement for CoreData, has some features and drawbacks but there will be (supposedly) a version for android soon, so if you really need to has that kind of support or integration for both platforms, [realm](http://realm.io/) could be a good alternative.

Also [this reading](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/SQLite-instead-of-core-data.html) could be helpful.